# Visual Studio project type for a WCF app to work under IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis

Is there a special project type for creating a WCF to be hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a special project type for hosing inside IIS. As long as you put the dlls in the bin folder and create a .svc file it will work. A standard web site project would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about VS 2008.

I can't see a way to have the WCF Service Library template use IIS for hosting. My advice is to create an ASP.NET Web Application, configure it to be IIS hosted, delete the Default.aspx file, and then add the WCF Service to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "WCF Service Application" template if you like, but as has been said, you don't really need anything special.